# xarray multi-dimensional interpolate to point without large matrix

Tags: interpolation, python-xarray

Is there a way to interpolate to specific points multi-dimensionally without creating an enormous array / looping?

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
xds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
xds['airx2'] = xds['air'] * 2
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(lat=[45, 60, 75], lon=[225, 320, 315],
                        time=pd.to_datetime(['2013-01-10', '2013-01-12', '2013-01-15'])))

# this seems to be very fast, but creates a large 3x3x3 array
# not ideal if I have 800 rows which will make a final array of 800x800x800
xds.interp(**pdf)

# this doesn't create a 800x800x800 array
# if there's 800 rows in the dataframe, but not vectorized
pd.concat([xds.interp(**row).to_array().to_dataframe('kelvin')
           for i, row in pdf.iterrows()])
```

Large array

[image]:

Desired result (if isn't looped):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to select from multiple dimensions using a list of multidimensional points (rather than sub-setting the data using orthogonal indices), you want to select from the data using DataArrays with a common index:

```
# create three indexer DataArrays with the DataFrame's index as their coordinate
lat_idx = pdf.lat.to_xarray()
lon_idx = pdf.lon.to_xarray()
time_idx = pdf.time.to_xarray()

# interpolate to these *points* at the lat/lon/time positions given
interped = xds.interp(lat=lat_idx, lon=lon_idx, time=time_idx)

# this can be dumped into pandas:
interped_df = interped.to_dataframe()
```

See the [docs on More Advanced Indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) for more info.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that's amazing. 

One long line
`pdf[['air', 'airx2']] = xds.interp(**{col: pdf[col].to_xarray() for col in df.columns}).to_dataframe()[['air', 'airx2']]`

Comment: Actually, even shorter:
`pdf[['air', 'airx2']] = xds.interp(pdf.to_xarray()).to_dataframe()[['air', 'airx2']]`

Comment: Whoa... I hadn't seen that syntax before! Cool!